# How to exclude a folder from rsync

Tags: rsync

I am using `rsync` to deploy a git branch with my production server. Currently, I got `js` files stored in two locations:

- assets/js/
- js/

When I run rsync using `--exclude js`, non of the both folders will be sync, while I want the `assets/js/` folder to be synced and the `js/` folder inside my root folder to be skipped. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the pattern for those files and directories:

using:

```
CWRULE [PATTERN_OR_FILENAME]
CWRULE,MODIFIERS [PATTERN_OR_FILENAME]
```

so you would have something like

```
CW- js/
```

For even more detailed info you can see the man page at the section

```
Include/Exclude Pattern Rules
```

from [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) link, hope it helps